# 回答が付いているこの質問に関して、削除の取り消しを提案します

Tags: 討議, 質問の削除

「[JSON.parse で uninitialized constant JSON というエラーが出る](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/q/41910/3054)」
この質問の削除の取り消しを提案します。
（現在削除済みですので、この質問の表示や削除の取り消しへの投票には[信用度2000点](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/moderator-tools)が必要なようです）

解決に到る回答が得られた後に質問を削除する行為は、回答者の意欲の低下につながります。
また、その既に得られている回答には[新しい質問](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/q/41920/3054)の解決につながるコメントも含まれています。

---

追記: 2018-03-02 に取り消しに3票が集まり、削除が取り消されました。

Answer (score 6, accepted):

削除の取り消しに賛成します。

また、Stack Exchange Meta の[この投稿](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/108683/341401)によると、回答が1つでも up-vote されると自分では削除できなくなるようです。Up-vote 重要ですね。