# 回答が投稿された後、質問者が質問をすぐ自己削除することはどの程度OKですか？

Tags: 討議, 質問の削除

質問者 A が質問をした後、回答者 B が回答を 1 つ投稿したとします。このとき、B の回答が upvote されるか他の回答が投稿されるまでの間、A は自分の質問を自己削除することができます。このとき回答も同時に削除されてしまいます。

このようなことが起こると、せっかく回答者 B が回答にかけた時間が無駄になってしまいます。また将来的に似た質問が投稿されたとき「重複」扱いにできず、別の回答者の時間も奪ってしまいます。

一方で、「こんな質問をしてしまった、恥ずかしい」などの理由から反射的に質問を削除したくなるお気持ちも分からなくはありません。(スタック・オーバーフローでは質問を削除しても信用度が高いユーザーからは内容が見えてしまうのであまり意味が無いのですが。)

ルールだけを考えると、スタック・オーバーフローに投稿されたものはクリエイティブ・コモンズ・ライセンスでライセンスされているので、質問者の意図に関係無く削除を取り消すことができます。実際、信用度が高いユーザーの削除取り消し票を集めることで取り消せます。

個人的には、せっかく有効そうな回答がついているのであれば削除を取り消して回答を upvote し、回答者の信用度をプラスしたいです。しかし、前述したようにそれを嫌がるお気持ちも分からなくはなく、どのようにすべきか悩んでいます。

#### 質問

- 回答がついた質問を質問者が特別な理由なく自己削除することは、どの程度 OK でしょうか？　たとえば下のようなグラデーションがありそうです。

  - とても良い：削除を許容すべきで、削除取り消しをするべきではない。
  - 良い：よっぽど良い回答がついている場合を除いて、削除して良い。
  - どちらでもない：削除された後その削除を取り消したい場合、各事例ごとにメタで議論をすべきだ。
  - 悪い：良い回答がついているなら削除すべきでない。もしされても、削除取り消しをするべきだ ("良い" 回答かどうかは、取り消し票が 3 票集まるかどうかで判断する)。
  - とても悪い：システム的に、回答がついたら upvote に関係なく削除できないようにすべきだ。
- 関連して、モデレーターだと一発で削除取り消しできてしまうのですが、モデレーター判断で削除取り消しをするのは OK でしょうか？

  - 削除取り消しをして、コメント等でこのメタ投稿へのリンクを提示する？
  - [質問とアカウントの紐付けが削除できる](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/96732/how-do-i-remove-my-name-from-a-post-in-accordance-with-cc-by-sa-3-0)ことについても伝えるべき？

ただし、「ログイン・クレデンシャルを公開してしまった」などの特別な理由があって削除したい場合は除きます。なおこのような場合は投稿の削除ではなく[モデレーターによる修正 (redact) で処理すべき](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/2869/19110)です。

ちなみに、過去一回だけメタで削除取り消しが議論されたことがあります： [回答が付いているこの質問に関して、削除の取り消しを提案します](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/2655/19110)

Comment: 関連？ https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/2094/

Comment: MSEでの関連投稿を見つけました: [When is it OK to vote to undelete posts that were deleted by their owners?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/106619/341401)

Comment: 他にも色々とありました: [Should we permit undeleting questions against the author’s will?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/51265/341401) ／ [Can a question be restored if the owner deletes it?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/100637/341401) ／ [Allow 25k+ community moderators to undelete self-deleted questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/53402/341401) ／ [How relevant are CC BY-SA terms to posters deleting posts?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/295632/341401)

Comment: 質問者本人は不必要になったから削除するので削除取り消しをモデレータが行ったとしても、今後その質問がメンテされるかは謎ですよね。

Answer (score 1):

削除があくまで自己都合であるなら、回答してくれた人に対しては何らかのコメントを残すのがコミュニティにおける最低限の礼儀かなぁと個人的には思っています。
ただ、削除の理由が妥当なものかを判断するためにレビューを回すところまでやる必要があるのかは難しいところです。

何か対策を行うとしたら案としては

1. 回答が付いた時点で(回答の評価に関わらず)削除が出来ないように変更する
2. 「英語で投稿しようとした場合」のように、削除のタイミングで簡単なメッセージを表示する
3. 「質問の削除」に対して軽微なペナルティを設ける(マイナス評価や一定時間新規質問を出来なくするなど)

Answer (score 1):

暫く考えていましたが、現時点での自分の意見を自己回答として残しておきます。

- 他の人の役にも立ちそうな回答がついた場合、なるべく削除して欲しくありません。それでも削除したくなった場合はその意見を尊重すべきだとは思いますが、最低限回答者への礼儀は果たして欲しいなと思います。
- 削除が起こった後、別のユーザーがその削除に反対することも許容すべきです。

  - 意味のある回答がついた質問が自己削除されてしまったのを発見したら、まずは質問者に削除の取り消しを丁寧に頼んでみるべきです。頼む方法が無い場合、[チャット](https://chat.stackexchange.com/?tab=site&host=ja.stackoverflow.com)や通報などでモデレーターに依頼することができます。
  - もしあなたが回答の投稿者で、削除を取り消したいなら、削除の取り消しをメタ (今いるこのサイト) に投稿し、削除の取り消し票を募ることができます。回答によって得られるはずだった信用度を得ることができるでしょう。(第三者がこの方法を取ることも OK だと思いますが、なるべく丁寧に行われるべきだと思います。)
  - 回答者が質問者の削除の意を汲み取りたい場合、他の手段として、同じ趣旨の質問を自己回答として投稿することも場合によっては良さそうです。ただし質問文を丸々コピー＆ペーストするのではなく自分でイチから再構成する必要があるでしょう (CC BY-SA なのでルールとしては出典を示した上でコピペできますが、それだと削除の意味が薄れてしまいます)。
  - もしあなたがモデレーターなら、[super-ping](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/119114/341401) と private chat を使ってそのユーザーに直接通知し、頼むことができます。モデレーター権限で直接削除取り消しをするのは避けるべきです。
- 有益な回答のついた質問を同じユーザーが何個も自己削除することは、あまり許容したくありません。このような場合はそのユーザーについてモデレーターに伝え、モデレーターはそのユーザーにこのメタ投稿を示すなどして、回答の価値を無駄にして欲しくないことを丁寧に伝えることになるでしょう。聞くは一時の恥、聞かぬは一生の恥……。