# 回答した質問を削除されてしまった

Tags: 討議, 完了, 質問の削除

[C# .NET FrameworkでKSプロパティにアクセスし、UVC拡張ユニットと通信したい](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/98103/c-net-framework%e3%81%a7ks%e3%83%97%e3%83%ad%e3%83%91%e3%83%86%e3%82%a3%e3%81%ab%e3%82%a2%e3%82%af%e3%82%bb%e3%82%b9%e3%81%97-uvc%e6%8b%a1%e5%bc%b5%e3%83%a6%e3%83%8b%e3%83%83%e3%83%88%e3%81%a8%e9%80%9a%e4%bf%a1%e3%81%97%e3%81%9f%e3%81%84)

こちらの質問への回答を行ったのですが、回答後に質問文を変更して追加の質問を記載してきたので、追加の質問は別質問にするようコメントしたら、質問を削除されてしまいました。
回答だけ貰って削除、というような行為が常態化すると問題があると思われますので、質問の削除の取り消しを提案します。

Comment: 現在は質問者さんにより、削除が取り消されています。
この質問では、主に個別のケースを扱っていたため、分かり易さのために「完了」としました。
もちろん、ご意見などは引き続きお寄せ下さい。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

削除の取り消しに賛成です。投票可能な方は、ぜひ投票していただければと思います。

#### 取り消しの仕方

[信用度2000以上](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/moderator-tools)の方は、削除の取り消しに投票できます。該当の質問の下部で可能です。3名の投票が集まると取り消されます。

参考: [過去の事例](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/2655/3054)（なお、この事例ではモデレーターが取り消しに投票しているように見えますが、当時はモデレーターではなかったことに注意して下さい。モデレーターは投票できません）

#### サイト初心者への案内を、より歓迎的にするために

特にサイトの初心者である質問者さんへは、説明する内容が多くなりがちですから、今回も苦労が有ったことと思います。その中で回答者さんがコメントで説明した内容は、このサイトの使い方に沿った正しい内容であったと思います。

しかし同時に自戒も込めた感想として、もっと上手くコメントできた筈とも思います。私たち、説明をする側は、以下の点に努力が必要です。

- 歓迎的な姿勢、トーンを崩さないこと
- 前提の知識が無い方にも分かり易い表現を選択すること

例えば、「この質問はクローズしてください」「強制クローズ対象です」「これは認められません」といった表現が積み重なり、質問者さんが次に何をすべきか解らなくなった可能性は十分に有ります。

[「コミュニティで大切にしたい価値観」](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/key-values)にもあるように、「強い言葉」は避けましょう。また、「クローズ」などのサイト特有の用語には説明が必要ですし、文脈によって別の意味で使うなどの混乱が無いように注意が必要です。

#### 他者による質問の改善

なお、質問のタイトルの不備の指摘も見られましたが、これはクローズする理由にはならないと思います。本文の内容をタイトルに反映するなどの編集は、質問者さん本人でなくとも可能で、歓迎される行為です。

クローズ投票、マイナス投票をする前に、選択肢の一つとして検討して下さい。

---

#### 追記: モデレーターとして

モデレーター権限の使用に慎重だという nekketsuuu さんのコメントに賛成です。

ただ今回は、誤解が有ったかも知れませんので、できればそれは解消したいです。最低限の権限の使用として、質問に私のコメントを追加しました。これは、「モデレーターメッセージ」とは違い、システム側からのメッセージが届く訳では無く、私個人のコメントとして、他のコメントと同列に並ぶものです。

Comment: 確かに言葉が強かったなと反省したい点はありました。次回コメントで指摘する場合は、注意しようと思います。

Answer (score 2):

今回のご質問についている[コメント](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/98103/#comment111598_98103)によると、radian さんはこの質問はクローズすべきというご意見なのだと理解しました。クローズされるべき質問の削除を取り消すべきというのは主張しづらいので、どうしたものかなと悩んでいます。

選択肢としては、

- (a) 質問者さんへお願いするなど何らかの方法で削除の取り消しをしたあと、編集をして Q&A を改善する、
- (b) この Q&A とは別に、要点をまとめた自己回答の Q&A を投稿していただいて保全する、
- (c) 削除取り消し票が集まるのを待つ、

あたりが思いつきます。radian さんはどのようになさりたいでしょうか。

個人的には、ナレッジベースを残したいという意図であれば (b) が手っ取り早いと思っています。今回のご回答は質問者さんの追記によると上手くいかなかったようなので、逆に上手くいく場合の質問を錬成すればご自身の回答を活かした Q&A を残せます。

また、無差別な質問削除をやめてほしいと伝えたいのみなのであれば、チャット等で伝えて済ませる方法もあります。不自然な質問の削除があまりにも続くようであれば、モデレーターに通報いただいた上で [super-ping かモデレーターメッセージで連絡する方法](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/119114/341401)も取れます。

なお補足として、この投稿を書いた時点では、メタ投稿からの削除の取り消しについてコミュニティの合意が取れておらず、定型的なフローが定まっていません。特に、モデレーター権限で強制的に削除を取り消すのは避けたいと考えています。参考: [回答が投稿された後、質問者が質問をすぐ自己削除することはどの程度OKですか？](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/2873/19110)

Comment: クローズすべきまでは言いませんが、本来であれば焦点が絞れていないとクローズされるよ、という感じのニュアンスです。元の質問文からすると、タイトルを改善すればクローズレベルではなかった、と判断したので回答しました。（今はタイトルを改善してもらってから回答した方が良かったなと思っています）

Comment: お恥ずかしながら、super-ping のリンク先を読んでも、どこから通報できるのかちょっとよく分かりませんでした…無差別な質問削除をやめてほしいと伝えたいのは確かなので、送って頂けるとよいのですが。

Comment: 本人が削除を取り消さず、かつ削除取り消し票が集まらなかった場合は、残念ですが諦める事にします。

Comment: @radian (b) は、質問者さんの意図とは関係なく、radian さんの目線で新しく質問を作ってそれにあった回答をしておくという手段です。あくまでナレッジベースの維持を目的としています。(a) での削除取り消しについて、新しい参加者である質問者さんにサイトの雰囲気を伝えると認識を改めていただけることはよくあることです。質問者さん側の都合があったのかもしれないですし、現時点でモラルの有無を論じるのは早計かと思います。「本来であれば強制クローズ対象です」というコメントに応じて削除された可能性もありそうですし。(c) については質問を[通報](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/flag-posts)してください。

Comment: ありがとうございます。質問の通報を行いました。

Comment: 書き方が難しいのですが、個人的には今回の件だけでモデレーター権限を使うのは慎重になりたい立場です。もっと何回も質問の削除が繰り返されているのであればモデレーター権限を使う必要がありますが、今回は 1 件削除されているのみですし、まずはコミュニティによる投票などを待ちたいです。（他のモデレーターの方が権限を使うのを止めるほどの意見ではないです。）

Answer (score 1):

使っている用語の解釈のズレだったのではないかと思われます。

コメントのやり取りや対処から推測すると、radianさんは「クローズ」を「この質問自身はいったん解決したものとして終了させる」という意味で使ったのではないですか？

しかしこのサイトでの「クローズ」は、「質問を停止・中断・キャンセル（・あるいは改善待ちの意味で保留）させる」というニュアンスを多分に含んでいると感じられます。

質問者さんは、そちらの解釈で意見されたと判断したので削除したように見受けられました。
しかも2つ目のコメントに「強制」クローズと強烈な表現で書かれていたのが更に助長した感じですね。

なのでこうした場合は「クローズ」と言うよりも「この質問自身はいったん解決したものとして回答を承認する」のと「新たな状況・疑問は別に新しい質問を立てる」という風に誘導した方が良いと思われます。

---

ただし、最初のコメントとしてもクローズはちょっと過敏だったように見えました。

回答として提案されたライブラリを使おうとしたがエラーになったという追記なので、質問者さんにとっては当初の目的が達成できていないのでまだ完全には解決していないと思われたのでしょう。

情報が取得出来たと確認するまでくらいは付き合っても良かったのでは？

Comment: そこは逆に言えば、エラーコードが取得出来る段階までは進めたということです。私としては、質問文を変えながら1質問で実質複数の質問をするのは許容できません。回答内容と質問文が噛み合わなくなるからです。もし最初の質問文についた回答、変更した後についた質問文に別についた回答みたいな状況になったらややこしくなるのでは？

Comment: 実は @radian さんの回答の方が削除されるかマイナス投票される可能性もあるのですよ。[一部の回答が削除される理由とその方法は？](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers) **質問の根本的な答えになっていない回答は削除される場合があります。... 外部サイトへの単なるリンク** おそらく私が同様の回答を書いた場合は、誰かからマイナス投票が付けられたでしょうね。実際にそのような仕打ちを受けた経験が何回もあります。

Comment: リンクだけではなく、ライブラリの説明文も書いていますが、それでも不足でしょうか？実際に試せるならサンプルを書いていたと思いますが、UVCカメラを所有していないのでこちらでは実際に試す事が出来ないんですよね。実際ライブラリを使うだけで解決する可能性があるのであれば、それ以上詳細な回答をするかどうかは回答者の裁量でしょう。（実際、先に進めているようですし）

Comment: また、少し話は逸れますが、kunifさんはコメントで回答に近いレベルの事を書き込んでいるのをよく目にしますが、コメント追加欄には「コメントを使って、情報の追加を求めたり、改善方法を提案したりします。コメントを使って質問に回答しないでください」と書かれているので、ヒントに近いレベルであれば回答を使うべきではないでしょうか。

Comment: @radian さん、まあ私の場合はもっと色々と紹介内容を多く記述してもいっぱいマイナス投票されましたからね。そこはたまたま誰かの琴線に触れてしまったかどうかの差ですね。そういう人に粘着されている(見つかるとマイナス投票される)ようです。なので私は今は自分に経験が無かったり試せない内容や単なる紹介はコメントだけに留めることが多いです。

Comment: 粘着されているという事情は存じていなかったので、そこはお気の毒です。私的には、間接的にでも解決に繋がりそうな情報であれば回答してあげたいとは思いますが（カメラ関連とかWeb情報も少なそうですし）、かといって間違った事も書きたくはないので、実際に試していないソースは載せたくないんですよね。件の回答は、「実際の質問に対して部分的回答にもなっていない」というのには該当しないと私は思っておりますが、もしそう感じたのであれば、躊躇せずマイナス票を入れてくださって結構です。

Comment: @radian さん、試していないソースを載せたくないのは私も同意しますね。何処かに使い方のサンプルを公開している記事や、そのライブラリを利用しているプロジェクトがあれば良かったのでしょうが無さそうですし。ただ追記された試した結果の質問内容にあったエラーコードを調べると下位4桁がバッファ無効だったので使い方の問題だろうと該当記事をコメントに紹介しておいたのが該当したようですね。だからそのくらいまでは付き合っても良かったのでは？と考えた訳です。

Comment: 「radian さんの回答の方が削除されるかマイナス投票される可能性」ですが、マイナス票はともかく、削除対象では無いはずです。
私にはなじみが無い分野なので、正確に評価できませんが radian さんの回答は完全では無く、部分的なものなのかも知れません。
それでも、このサイトの回答として正当なものです。
これは、[現在のヘルプ](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers)の表現が誤解を招いているかも知れませんね。
削除対象なのは、「根本的【な】答えになっていない」では無く、「根本的【に】回答になっていない」がより適切な表現でしょう。
つまり、削除対象なのは、回答として「箸にも棒にも掛からない」レベルの投稿です。

Comment: @mjy さん、私もヘルプ記事の文言を基にカウンター的な可能性を意見として書いただけですので、本当に削除されるとは思っていません。対象の質問・回答それぞれに対してそういう見方もありますよ程度ですね。ただ先にコメントしたように私の場合は同様な内容でもう少し詳細に書いたつもりの回答でマイナス投票が多数集まったこともあるので、ちょっとした何かの差がどう転ぶか分からないとも言えます。

Answer (score 0):

削除はすでに取り消しされてるようなので以下は一般論

私個人は質問者が自己の判断で削除した質問について取り消しの投票はしません。SOのシステム/規約上は投票の方が優先なので取り消しがけしからんとまでは言いませんが。

当該の質問がナレッジとして興味深いものなのであれば、自分で同じ質問をして回答することもできるので、それで用が足ります。

> 回答だけ貰って削除、というような行為が常態化すると問題

が実態としてそうなのであればシステムとして「回答がついた質問は削除できない」というような対処をすべき話かと思います。